# Loading a certain area of HTML from an external domain webpage into a div

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, web, screen-scraping

I'm currently designing a website for a company that uses an external site to display information about its clients. Currently, their old website just puts a link to the external profile of each client. however with this rebuild, I wondered if there was any way to load a specific portion of the external site onto their new page.

I've done my research, and I've found it's possible using jQuery and AJAX (with a bit of a mod) but all the tutorials relate to a div tag being lifted from the external site then loaded into the new div tag on the page.

Here's my problem: after reviewing the source code of the external source, the line of HTML I want isn't contained in a named DIV (other than the master wrap and I can't load that!)

The tag I need is literally: `<p class="currentAppearance"> data </p>`

It's on a different line for each profile so I can't just load line 200 and hope for the best.

Does anyone have any solution (preferably using php) that searches for that tag on an external page and then loads the specific tag into a div?

I hope I've been clear I am quite new to all this back end stuff!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would use to grab the content from the webpage:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

```
$url = 'http://www.some-domain.com/some-page';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$htmlContent = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Then using `DomDocument` (http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) you'll be able to access the right div based on its ID for instance.

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlContent);
foreach ($pElements as $pEl) {
  if ($pEl->getAttribute('class') == 'currentAppearance') {
    $pContent =  $pEl->nodeValue;
  }
}
```

`$pContent` is now set with the content of the paragraph with class `currentAppearance`

Comment: Thanks for this but as I said the actual data isn't in a div, it's a Paragraph tag defined with a class tag. Would this method work with that?

Comment: Thanks so much for your rapid and accurate response!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp) syntax to grab it out of the document.